# cx_Oracle error message

Tags: python, oracle

I installed cx_Oracle using `python -m pip install cx_Oracle --pre`. My python version is 3.5.1. When I run a script that contains import cx_Oracle, I get the error

> cx_Oracle.Databse Error: DPI-1050: Oracle Client Library must be at release 11.2 or higher

I picked up the command above from https://oracle.github.io/python-cx_Oracle/ where it is written that

> cx_Oracle is a Python extension module that enables access to Oracle Database and conforms to the Python database API specification. This module is currently built against **Oracle Client 11.2**, 12.1 and 12.2 and Python 2.7, 3.4, 3.5 and 3.6. For more information on the database API specification, see here.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Which version of the Oracle client do you have on your machine?

Comment: 10.2.0.3.0. By the way, I bypassed this problem by writing INSERT statements to a file and then running the file on PL/SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running behind a proxy? I was unable to install cx_Oracle (or any packages) on my work machine, because of this issue. The following worked for me:

```
pip --proxy (insert proxy here) install cx_Oracle
```

If not, if you are using Anaconda, can you open the Anaconda Navigator and install it on your machine or to any environment(s):

[image: Screenshot from my Anaconda Navigator]

Answer (score 0):

I had run into this error. It was caused by use of functionality that was not available in the oracle instant client. I was trying to use the callTimeout attribute of the Connection class, but it only works if you install a newer version of the oracle instant client.